# How to count repeated special characters in a url and append to list?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

> I have list of two websites and I want to count '.' dot and '-' hyphen
>   number of times it repeated and I want to assign this to the empty
>   list for each iteration in for loop. When I executed below code it
>   counts dots and hyphen but for each iteration its counts previous
>   value and increase the count like [1,2,3,6,12...] but I want to store
>   each iteration values separate in list like [1,3,2,5....] how to do?

```
tdots=[]
tphen = []
dots = 0
phen = 0
named_url = ['www.facebook.com','yahoo.com/index-true']

for i in named_url:
    for j in i:
        if '.' in str(j):
            dots = dots + 1
            Dots = []
            Dots.append(dots)
        else:
            print('No more "."')
    tdots.append(sum(Dots))        
for i in named_url:
    for j in i:
        if '-' in str(j):
            phen = phen + 1
            Phen = []
            Phen.append(phen)
        else:
            print('No more "-"')
    tphen.append(sum(Phen))
print(tdots,'Dots')
print(tphen,'Hyphen')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
dots = []
phens = []
named_url = ['www.facebook.com','yahoo.com/index-true']

for name in named_url:
    dots.append(name.count('.'))

for name in named_url:
    phens.append(name.count('-'))

tdots = sum(dots)
tphens = sum(phens)

print(dots, phens, tdots, tphens)
```

Output:-

```
[2, 1]
[0, 1]
3
1
```

Comment: Is my question is wrong? I don't know why I got negative -1 should I format my question? thanks for answer it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
named_url = ['www.facebook.com','yahoo.com/index-true']
dots_sum = []
hyphens_sum = []

dots = []
hyphens = []
for url in named_url:
    dots.append(url.count('.'))
    hyphens.append(url.count('-'))

print(sum(dots), sum(hyphens))
dots_sum.append(sum(dots))
hyphens_sum.append(sum(hyphens))
dots.clear()
hyphens.clear()
```

Code that works for that using [count](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-function-count/) which then appends the sum of the dots and hyphens found in the list to two other lists and then clears the two lists that were only holding the counts of dots per url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to make this easier:

```
from collections import Counter
named_url = ['www.facebook.com', 'yahoo.com/index-true']
for url in named_url:
    c = Counter(url)
    dots = c["."]
    dash = c["-"]
    print("{} contains: {} dot(s) and {} hyphen(s)".format(url, dots, dash))
```

Output:

```
www.facebook.com contains: 2 dot(s) and 0 hyphen(s)
yahoo.com/index-true contains: 1 dot(s) and 1 hyphen(s)
```